# convert 1d array to length of 2d array column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array

The dataframe contains two array columns which are 1d and 2d arrays.

```
| 1d_col                    | 2d_col                     |
| --------------------------| ---------------------------|
| ["negative", "positive"]  | [["zero", ""], ["one", ""]]|
| ["positive", "negative"]  | [["two", ""], ["zero", ""]]|
| ["negative"]              | [["minus", ""]]            |
| ["positive"]              | [["three", ""]]            |
```

I need to convert 1d_col to same length of 2d_col. The output dataframe should look like this.

```
| 2d_col                     |new_col                                              | 
| ---------------------------| ----------------------------------------------------|
| [["zero", ""], ["one", ""]]| [["negative", "negative"], ["positive", "positive"]]|
| [["two", ""], ["zero", ""]]| [["positive", "positive"], ["negative", "negative"]]|
| [["minus", ""]]            | [["negative", "negative"]]                          |
| [["three", ""]]            | [["positive", "positive"]]                          |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "1d_col": [
            ["negative", "positive"],
            ["positive", "negative"],
            ["negative"],
            ["positive"],
        ],
        "2d_col": [
            [["zero", ""], ["one", ""]],
            [["two", ""], ["zero", ""]],
            [["minus", ""]],
            [["three", ""]],
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df["new_col"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: [
        [item] * len(x["2d_col"]) if len(x["2d_col"]) >= 2 else [item] * 2
        for item in x["1d_col"]
    ],
    axis=1,
)
df = df.drop(columns=["1d_col"])
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
                2d_col                                       new_col
0  [[zero, ], [one, ]]  [[negative, negative], [positive, positive]]
1  [[two, ], [zero, ]]  [[positive, positive], [negative, negative]]
2          [[minus, ]]                        [[negative, negative]]
3          [[three, ]]                        [[positive, positive]]
```